# How can I convert a file into a dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary

I am wondering how I can take a .txt file and convert it into a dictionary in Python. The .txt would store information for the map with some names and numbers inside of it.

Example of what the .txt file will look like:

```
{"Jerry" : 2353543}
```

I would like to take this text file and add it to a dictionary in python. Example:

```
file = open("random.txt",)
read_file = file.read()
#Then somehow add this read_file into the contact information to produce:
contact_information = {"Jerry" : 2345355}
```

At the end of this the code will write back to the .txt file.

Comment: "Contain a map" does not define your input format.  Supply that and your coding attempt, including the [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of what didn't work for you.  *Then* you'll perhaps have a Stack Overflow question.

Answer (score 0):

If the file contents consist solely of a string that constitutes a legal Python `dict` literal, which recursively contains solely Python literals, you can use `ast.literal_eval` for this:

```
>>> data = '{"Jerry" : 2353543}'
>>> import ast
>>> d = ast.literal_eval(data)
>>> d
{'Jerry': 2353543}
>>> d['Jerry']  # It's an actual dict!
2353543
```

Unlike `eval`, [`ast.literal_eval` cannot execute arbitrary code](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval), so it doesn't introduce the same safety/stability issues that `eval` does.

`json.load`/`json.loads` might also work (and would work in this specific case), but it's generally more limited, since it only allows a slight superset of the JSON spec (e.g. allowing integers as keys), but doesn't support `tuple`, `set`, `bytes`, etc. If your file is *intended* to be JSON, use it, but if it's *intended* to be a Python literal, use `ast.literal_eval`.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`json`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) module to load data from your file.

```
>>> import json
>>> f = open("random.txt")
>>> contact_information = json.load(f, parse_int=int)
>>> contact_information
{'Jerry': 2353543}
>>> contact_information["Jerry"]
2353543
```

Comment: Is there a way I can turn contact_information into a map

Comment: @Learningcoding13 : The `json.load` call returns that mapping.